# Show dialog while using Android Annotation

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-annotations

In my Activity called **TestAPIActivity_**, there's a click event to display a dialog:

```
@Click(R.id.test_account_edit_avatar_btn)
void editAvatar() {
    pickDialog = DialogFactory.createPickPhotoDialog(this);
    pickDialog.show();
}
```

while clicking that button, a exception throw out:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is    not for an application.
```

I've checked the "**this**" passing into createPickPhotoDialog() is a **TestAPIActivity_**. Does anyone encounter this problem while using Android Annotation? What's the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Did you find the answer to this question?

Comment: I do not think it's a problem in AndroidAnnotations, maybe it is in your factory code. Actually `@Click` just sets up the listener.